# Neo4j, Cypher Use COUNT with COLLECT to return JSON

Tags: json, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to return a JSON object like this:

```
{   "rels": [
    {
      "rel": "type_1",
      "foos": 15
    },
    {
      "rel": "type_2",
      "foos": 2073
    },
    {
      "rel": "type_3",
      "foos": 23
    }   ] }
```

Using the query.

```
MATCH (n:bar)<-[r:REL]-(n1:foo)
WHERE n.bar_id='1234567890'
RETURN collect({rel: r.rel_status, foos: count(r.rel_status)}) AS rels
```

Where the REL relationships have a property called rel_status.

> ERROR: Can't use aggregate functions inside of aggregate functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're attempting to use `count()` inside a `collect()`, which isn't allowed. You'll need to do these one step at a time.

```
MATCH (n:bar)<-[r:REL]-(:foo)
WHERE n.bar_id='1234567890'
WITH r.rel_status as rel, count(r) as foos
RETURN collect({rel: rel, foos: foos}) AS rels
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!